# Haskell, lacks an accompanying binding?

Tags: haskell

this is my program (I realise it's not an entirely useful program):

```
data Temp a = Something1 | Something2 deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

length :: Temp a -> Integer
Something1 = 0
Something2 = 1
```

and I keep getting the error message:

Haskellfile.lhs:3:3:
    The type signature for `length' lacks an accompanying binding
      (You cannot give a type signature for an imported value)

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
data Temp a = Something1 | Something2 deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

length :: Temp a -> Integer
length Something1 = 0
length Something2 = 1
```

It's better to change `length` to something else, to avoid clash with Prelude's length. If you want to use your length as "default", add

```
import Prelude hiding (length)
import qualified Prelude
```

on the beginning, and refer to Prelude's version with `Prelude.length`. Not recommended.

By the way if your `Temp` doesn't depend on `a`, you might consider

```
data Temp = Something1 | Something2 deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
```

Comment: @user997112 No problem. That happens to anyone. Keep learning!

Comment: The second version is preferable in most cases if you are exporting the `length` function; then the user can just import qualified.